# QuantLib installation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, quantlib-swig

Can someone assist with up-to-date instructions for the installation of the QuantLib in Python. I have used the instructions on this link https://vineetv.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/installing-quantlib-python-windows/ and followed the video on this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWMT78XJFJE
but I keep on getting errors in building the solutions. I am new to programming.

Comment: Please post the error log here

Comment: This was the error;  3>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib'. I looked for the solution on this platform and when I implemented it I still got the same errors

Comment: Try installing Windows SDK for your platform as described here: `https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a2f61b7-3c01-4767-9a30-e897dc240e60/lnk1104-cannot-open-file-ucrtdlib?forum=vssetup`

Answer (score 4):

Install Anaconda 4.3.1 ([link](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)), then open a Command Prompt as Admin and type:

**pip install QuantLib-Python**

For me, this only worked on the latest version of Anaconda including Python 3.6, think the QuantLib-Python package was implemented in PIP only very recently.